# Could not find class oracle.security.pki.oraclewallet

Tags: android, oracle, ojdbc

Hello I try to get data from my oracle database, I use ojdbc14.jar. There is no error in the code but I got this error in the run time `05-17 10:41:06.846: E/dalvikvm(456): Could not find class 'oracle.security.pki.OracleWallet', referenced from method oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.getSecretStoreCredentials`
 How to fix this error. This is my code to get data from database

```
try
    {
        String username = getDataFromOraDB();
        TextView tv = new TextView(this);
        tv.setText(username);
    }
    catch(SQLException e)
    {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.getMessage(), 1).show();
    }
    catch(ClassNotFoundException e)
    {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.getMessage(), 1).show();
    }
}

public String getDataFromOraDB() throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException
{
    String name = null;
    String jdbcURL = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe";
    String user = "SYSTEM";
    String password = "radit";

    try
    {
        DriverManager.registerDriver(new oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver());
        Connection conn;
        ResultSet rs;
        Statement stmt;
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(jdbcURL, user, password);
        stmt = conn.createStatement();
        rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT name FROM IDENTITY");
        if(rs.next())
        {
            name = rs.getString("name");
        }
    }
    catch(java.sql.SQLException e)
    {
        System.out.println("The exception is " + e.toString());
    }
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), name, 1).show();
    return name;
}
```

I'll appreciate any help. Thank you.

Comment: as this OracleWallet class is not available in oracle.security.pki package..

Comment: than how to make it possible in my project because I read from the internet the some folks are able to connect to oracle with ojdbc14.jar

Comment: did u cal this getSecretStoreCredentials() any where

Comment: no.. I don't call it anywhere

Comment: from ur error code OracleWallet class is not found..so just download jar file and import to ur workspace :http://www.findjar.com/jar/com.oracle/oc4j/11/jars/oraclepki.jar.html

Comment: Can you tell me how to download the oraclepki.jar? I doesn't see any download button there.

Comment: http://www.findjar.com/class/oracle/security/pki/OracleWallet.html

Comment: well actually it gives me 2 options oraclepki.jar and oraclepki103.jar, I clicked them but I still directed to another page, so I still unable to download the jar.

Answer (score -1):

Add following permission to your **AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
```

Comment: Where is your permission :)